# Сотые милисекунды

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток.
Собственно вопрос - как получить таймер с точностью до сотых миллисекунды ?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что сама процедура запуска таймера будет выполнятся дольше. Да и GC никогда не делал java такой точной.

Можно конечно попробовать на базе Thread::Sleep сделать (он умеет делать такие задержки - как минимум по сигнатуре).

Может скажете, какую задачу решаете?

Comment: у меня тоже по этому поводу серьезные сомнения, особенно учитывая что результат должен  отображаться. Задачу решаю не я - высокоточный таймер, зачем он человеку не знаю, просто стало интересно то ли лыжи не едут, то ли ... знаний у меня не хватает) Когда понадобился высокоточный таймер под windows городил велосипед и считал тики.

Comment: Я сильно сомневаюсь, что для андроида нужна такая точность. Даже если отображать, для пользователя сотые секунды уже не заметны.

Если где то на мобильных устройствах и заработает, так это на playbook'ах - он на базе qnx.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но даже qnx системы тут пасуют, когда то копал эту тему для пк (не сильно углубленно другу помогал зачет автоматом получить ) обычно когда точность микросекунды или рядом решения с ос не подходят, думал может изменилось что то, или я не достаточно глубоко копал, все же в реальных примерах я это не использовал.

Comment: я не утверждаю, что на qnx оно будет гарантированно работать, но если бы мне спросили, где заработает - андроид, айось или плейбук, то  я бы ответил, что на первых двух не верю, что будет работать, а вот на плейбуке теоретически - да.

Comment: хм...реатлайм оси, это хорошо, но вот жава машина может все испортить. Случится стоп ворлд и вся ваша точность.... есть JRockit который хочет позиционируется как рт, но там свои приколы...
Вообще по своему опыту необходимости в тайкой точности я еще не встречал, даже для управления процессом с переходный процессом в ~1 сек (гидравлика/пневматика) достаточно 10 мсек. Ну это так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИМХО это невозможно на Android'е - ну то есть таймер то сделать можно, но точность не будет миллисекундной.

Для таких дел существуют специальные ОС т.н. операционные системы реального времени [RT OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

Linux не является real-time OS

Comment: для хорошего ответа желательно ссылочку на официальную документацию или исследования.

Answer (score 2):

[[@gadfil](/users/9113/gadfil)](/users/9113/gadfil), а какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слова "получить таймер с точностью до сотых миллисекунды" ?

Если в системе есть подходящий аппаратный таймер, то функции (POSIX) `clock_settime()`, `clock_gettime()` и `clock_getres()` работают с структурой, где время представлено с наносекундами.

Какой реально момент времени (относительно вызывавшего кода) будет возвращен в `clock_gettime()` это  другой вопрос. Результат какой-то момент времени между началом и концом системного вызова.

По сути можно только утверждать, что значение времени (в нанах) следующего вызова будет больше, чем предыдущего.